# referencing listing with custom caption using autoref

Tags: hyperref, listings

I'm trying to use the `listings` package to show some pseudocode. For that I want to add some keywords and a special environment which is used for all pseudocode listings. Additionally the referencing label should state "algorithm X.Y" instead of "listing X.Y". While the caption itself is correcty, the references using `\autoref{...}` still display "listings X.Y".

Here is small example of the issue:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{algocaption}{Algorithm \thenalg}
\newcounter{nalg}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thenalg}{\thechapter .\arabic{nalg}}
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[1][]
{   
    \refstepcounter{nalg} 
    \captionsetup{labelformat=algocaption,labelsep=colon} 
    \lstset{ 
        frame=tblr,
        numbers=left, 
        keywords={
            ,input
            ,output
            ,if
            ,else
            ,for
            ,foreach
            ,while
            ,end
        },
        numbers=left,
        xleftmargin=.04\textwidth,
        #1 
    }
}
{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\begin{algorithm}[caption={Integer division.}, label={alg:test}]
input: test
\end{algorithm}
\autoref{alg:test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are some `algorithm` packages already, no need to use `listings` for this

Answer (score 2):

The `\autoref` command tries to detect the underlying counter for the reference, this is `lstlisting` in this case and looks for a corresponding `\lstlistingautorefname`, which is not defined so far. This has to be provided then.

The unfortunate feature for this that each `lstlisting` environment still has the same counter. And other `non-algorithm` environments from `listings` will now provide the wrong `autoref` - name.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{algocaption}{Algorithm \thenalg}

\newcounter{nalg}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thenalg}{\thechapter.\arabic{nalg}}
\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[1][]
{   
  \refstepcounter{nalg}% 
    \captionsetup{labelformat=algocaption,labelsep=colon} 
    \lstset{ 
        frame=tblr,
        numbers=left, 
        keywords={
            ,input
            ,output
            ,if
            ,else
            ,for
            ,foreach
            ,while
            ,end
        },
        numbers=left,
        xleftmargin=.04\textwidth,
        #1 
    }
}
{}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\providecommand*{\lstlistingautorefname}{Algorithm}
}



\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\begin{algorithm}[caption={Integer division.}, label={alg:test}]
input: test
\end{algorithm}
\autoref{alg:test}
\end{document}
```